# Comma separated string for list

Tags: python, beginner

I do not have an intention to ask for an answer, but I want to know if my answer is good for a two-week Python beginner?

**Question:** (Automate the Boring Stuff with Python/ page 102)

***[Comma Code](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter4/#calibre_link-187)***

Say you have a list value like this:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
```

> Write a function that takes a list value as an argument and returns a
>   string with all the items separated by a comma and a space, with `and`
>   inserted before the last item. For example, passing the previous spam
>   list to the function would return:
>
> > apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
>
> But your function should be able to work with any list value passed to
>   it.

**My Answer:**

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
def sentence(i):
    for n in range(0, len(spam) - 1):
        print(spam[n], end=', ')
    print('and ' + spam[-1])
sentence(spam)
```

Comment: Your function is not actually "able to work with any list value passed to it., because it relies on the globally defined list `spam` and not the argument it is passed (which you named `i`).

Comment: Moreover, the implementation is incorrect, an empty list (`spam = []`) will result in an exception: `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: Moreover, your function returns `None` instead of the string specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function isn't returning anything. You should be building a string and returning it from your function. `str.join()` will be useful for building your string, return it with the `return` keyword.

Comment: After reviewing my code, I have realized that my function won't work if I use another list. I will consider your feedback so as to rewrite my program.
Thank you for letting me know the errors in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Since testing falls under the general heading of code review, I'm just going to review your testing strategy.

The question says:

> your function should be able to work with any list value passed to it.

but you are not testing this; you're only testing the single example that was given to you (and which, as it happens, you've hard-coded into your function).  Here's how you could test it:

```
print(sentence(['eggs', 'bacon', 'spam', 'bacon']))
```

Does this print the string `eggs, bacon, spam, and bacon`?  If not, why?  (Try to understand the bug before you fix it -- don't just change things randomly until it works!)

An even better test would be:

```
assert sentence(spam) == "apples, bananas, tofu, and cats"
assert sentence(['eggs', 'bacon', 'spam', 'bacon']) == "eggs, bacon, spam, and bacon"
```

Add this to your program, and then fix the `sentence` function so that neither line of code causes your program to fail.  This is called "test driven development" -- write the test first that says how you want the function to work, then write the function until the test passes!

Comment: I am grateful to your reply. I have realized that my program, as you said, have been hard-coded with the `spam` list. After reading your review, I will check my code again with your two `assert` lines.
Once again, thank you for letting me know what to do next.